# Cant write to file NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I've been able to write to files before in almost this exact same way, however now it is giving me trouble. I loop through this function resetting variables that I delete towards the end of the function (see code below). The loop that calls this function runs successfully for anywhere between 3-9 times and then it always breaks on the file writing with this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'screenshots/item4/record/record.html'
```

NOTE: It is NOT always item4.

The directories are always made successfully but then the file can't write sometimes. Here is the code:

```
async function save_and_erase() {
  let path = await 'screenshots/item'+recordCount;
  await makeDirectory(path);
  await makeDirectory(path+'/base');
  await makeDirectory(path+'/record');
  await saveFile(path+'/base/base.html',storage['index_html']);
  await saveFile(path+'/base/base.png',storage['index_screenshot']);
  await saveFile(path+'/record/record.html',storage['record_html']);
  await saveFile(path+'/record/record.png',storage['record_screenshot']);
  await delete storage['record_html'];
  await delete storage['record_screenshot'];
  await recordCount++;
};
async function makeDirectory(path) {
    mkdirp(path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
};
async function saveFile(path, content) {
    await fs.writeFile(path, content, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't think `writeFile` returns a promise, so your `await` in `saveFile` will return immediately. You're not awaiting `mkdirp`, although I doubt that returns a promise either. I believe you have to use `utils.promisify` to make those commands return promises...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by @Heretic clearly mentions that the `writeFile` does not return the `Promise` object by default.

You can look at `util` library to promisify your functions if you are using latest versions of Node

otherwise, changing the functions as following would do the trick:

```
function makeDirectory(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mkdirp(path, function(err) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve();
        }); 
    })
};
function saveFile(path, content) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(path, content, (err) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve();
        });
    })
};
```

Note that you can only `await` the functions which returns a `promise`. Thus, you do not require `await` for `delete` and increment operations